# JS Moving prototype function addition outside of 'Scene'

Tags: javascript, object, animation, prototype, game-development

I am writing a basic mouse accuracy game in JS and am trying to move as much code as possible to the global level so that it can be used in multiple scenes. The game involves moving a crosshair (using the mouse) and clicking on squares (properties and methods of which are represented by the Trgt object), which shrink slightly every frame.

The Trgt object stores information about the targets (how big they are, how fast they disappear) and also things that happen to the targets (e.g. they shrink, they get hit/clicked on etc).

[See my project on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roadrunnersf/8npwvyb4/81/).

The game has 4 scenes which run in this order: Intro -> Play -> (Win OR Lose).

I have written a constructor for the Trgt object near the start of the code. The constructor is declared at the global level rather than inside a scene.

The methods are being added to the Trgt prototype within the 'Play'scene, but I would like to move all of the methods associated with the prototype outside of the play scene, under the constructor so it looks neater, and so that these methods can be used in subsequent scenes (e.g. if I want to add more levels).

When I try to move it then none of my code seems to run. I am met with a blank screen. What am I doing wrong here?

I also want to  move the mouse click handler from the 'Play' scene outside of that scene (as I have successfully done for the mouse click handling for all of the other scenes, both those before and those after the Play scene).

I suspect my problem might be to do with use of 'this' but I've been playing around with it for quite a while and am pretty stumped.

The method code that is within the play scene is as follows:

```
  Trgt.prototype = {
    shrinkTypeChooser: function() {
      this.shrinkType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1; //random integer beween 1 & 5
    },
    shrink: function() {
      this.s -= this.shrinkRate;
      switch (this.shrinkType) {
        case 1: //shrink from top left
          break;
        case 2: //shrink from top right
          this.x += this.shrinkRate;
          break;
        case 3: //shrink from bottom right
          this.x += this.shrinkRate;
          this.y += this.shrinkRate;
          break;
        case 4: //shrink from bottom left
          this.y += this.shrinkRate;
          break;
        case 5: //shrink to centre
          this.x += this.shrinkRate / 2;
          this.y += this.shrinkRate / 2;
          break;
      }
    },

    hit: function() {
      clicks++;
      score++;

      this.reset();
      this.shrinkRate *= this.shrinkMult;
    },
    miss: function() { //called when a click DOES NOT hit a target
      clicks++;
    },
    diss: function() { //called when a target disapears
      disses++;
      this.reset();
    },
    reset: function() { //reset trgt size to base values and chooses a new random position
      trgt.shrinkTypeChooser();
      this.s = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sUpper) + this.sLower; //random trgt size
      this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - this.s));
      this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.s));
    },
    chooseColor: function() {
      if (hair.x >= trgt.x && hair.x <= (trgt.x + trgt.s) && hair.y >= trgt.y && hair.y <= (trgt.y + trgt.s)) {
        //inside target
        trgt.fillColor = 'red'
      } else {
        //outside target
        trgt.fillColor = 'blue'
      }
    },
    draw: function() {
      this.chooseColor();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.s, this.s);
      ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor;
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add all relevant information. Which exact methods are you talking about? How does the code around look etc.

Comment: I have added as much more information as I think as I can think of. The methods in question are those quoted in the code section of the post. If there is anything else specifically that I can add then I'd be happy to do so.